# Codeigniter Join tables from 2 databases

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is it possible to join 2 tables from different database?

Here is my query

```
public function getschedule($section){
    $this->dbsections->select('*');
    $this->dbsections->from($section);

    //I want to join the column "teacher" of the "section_name" table that is in the "dbsections" database
    //to the "id" column of the "teachers" table in the "dbusers" database

    $this->dbsections->join('teachers', 'teachers.ID = '.$section.'.TEACHER');
    $query = $this->dbsections->get();

    $query = $this->dbsections->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

This code gives me error, obviously. I also tried

```
$this->dbsections->join('dbusers.teachers', 'teachers.ID = '.$section.'.TEACHER');
```

and

```
$this->dbsections->join('dbusers.teachers', 'teachers.ID = dbsections.'.$section.'.TEACHER');
```

But both gives me error

> Error Number: 1096
>
> No tables used
>
> SELECT *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `table name` in select * as

```
$this->dbsections->select("$section.*");// write tour table name before *
```

And Remove one time

```
   //  $query = $this->dbsections->get();
```

Comment: The extra $query line actually made it worked, I didn't noticed it. Thank you